# Eliminar comentarios en visual studio code (tengo un programa con mas de 5mil lineas)

Tags: css, html5, reactjs, visual-studio, progressbar

tengo una programa con extension .p que es de progress, este programa tiene como 5000 lineas, mi consulta es lo siguiente hay alguna extension en visual studio code que me elimine todos los comentarios? por ejemplo
Yo quiero que me elimine todo lo que esta dentro de un comentario,
/*
Este es una prueba, y quiero eliminar lo que esta dentro de este comentario
*/

osea quiero que el codigo quede limpio y sin comentarios hay alguna posibilidad de hacer esto?

pd: los comentarios en este programa empíeza con /* y termina con */

Estare atento a cualquier respuesta

Comment: Puedes echarle un vistazo a la extensión [Remove Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=plibither8.remove-comments).

Comment: Google no muerde...